# Covariate in a MCMC regression

Tags: regression, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, ancova, predictor

I am using MCMCglmm ([vignette is here](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/MCMCglmm/vignettes/CourseNotes.pdf)) and am willing to add a covariate.

If I were to be doing a standard linear model, I would for example choose a type 1 Sum of Squares and place my covariate in first position to make sure successive variables are computed on the remaining variance but I don't know if the same type of logic applies to a MCMC regression.

Ultimately, my question is **how can one add a covariate to a MCMC regression?** Of course, an answer that is specific to the function MCMCglmm is very much welcome.

Comment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0307904X05001010, the paper describes the issues and solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a short chat with the author of MCMCglmm, [Jarrod Hadfield](http://jarrod.bio.ed.ac.uk/jarrod.html). He said

> There is no option for doing sequential tests in MCMCglmm [..] Certainly, if two predictors are confounded and one (or both) has an effect, then sequential tests can report significance for the first predictor while non-sequential tests may report significance for neither, but this can often be revealed by jointly testing the two effects or looking at the posterior correlation between the two parameters.